# Find the position and item of difference in given 2 array of strings in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string

```
string[] test1 = { "Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Serial", "Beta","Power" };
string[] test2 = { "Alpha", "Gamma", "Serial", "Beta" };
```

Need output:

**Beta** is missing from **position 1** in **test2** array

**Power** is missing from **position 6** in **test2** array

Here we cant ignore even for duplicate. we need the exact difference even if one is missing in the duplicate records like here we have Beta twice but only the first position is missing.

Was using the below but this has an implicit way of showing distinct values so below yields no value.

```
test1.Except(test2)
```

If anyone could help me get the code right?

Comment: What should be printed if `test2` has element missing from `test1` or it is guaranteed to have only elements present in first one? As for how - you can have a `for` loop to go through elements of `test1` and  variable to track position in `test2`(and change this variable dependent on what happens).

Comment: It can be either ways. test1 or test2 can have missing elements same way.

Comment: OK, but consider these two simple arrays: `string[] test1 = { "Alpha" };  string[] test2 = { "Beta" }`.  How would you know from these two arrays which element is expected to be at position 0?  Is it "Alpha", or "Beta"?  How do you know if the expected order is `{ "Alpha", "Beta" }` or `{ "Beta", "Alpha" }`?  Seems you have to consider this as part of your solution, especially if you want your function to behave the same if you swap the two input arrays with each other (e.g. `CheckMissing(test1, test2)` vs `CheckMissing(test2, test1)`).

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you but I'm sure there is an easier solution.

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] test1 = { "Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Serial", "Beta", "Power" };
        string[] test2 = { "Alpha", "Gamma", "Serial", "Beta" };

        var groups = test1.Select((value, index) => new
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Value = value,
            Total = test1.Count(x => x.Equals(value)),
            Indexes = test1.FindAllIndexof(value)
        }).GroupBy(x => x.Value).Select(x => x.First())
            .Union(test2.Select((value, index) => new
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Value = value,
                Total = test2.Count(x => x.Equals(value)),
                Indexes = test2.FindAllIndexof(value)
            }).GroupBy(x => x.Value).Select(x => x.First())).ToList();

        var processedValues = new List<string>();
        foreach (var currentGroup in groups)
        {
            if (processedValues.Contains(currentGroup.Value))
                continue;

            var groupToCompare = groups.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == currentGroup.Value && x.Id != currentGroup.Id);
            if (groupToCompare == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{currentGroup.Value} is missing in positions {string.Join(",", currentGroup.Indexes)}");
            }
            else if (currentGroup.Total < groupToCompare.Total)
            {
                var differentIndexes = groupToCompare.Indexes.OrderByDescending(x => x).Skip(currentGroup.Indexes.Length - 1);
                Console.WriteLine($"{currentGroup.Value} is missing in positions {string.Join(",", differentIndexes)}");
            }
            else if (currentGroup.Total > groupToCompare.Total)
            {
                var differentIndexes = currentGroup.Indexes.OrderByDescending(x => x).Skip(currentGroup.Indexes.Length - 1);
                Console.WriteLine($"{currentGroup.Value} is missing in positions {string.Join(",", differentIndexes)}");
            }

            processedValues.Add(currentGroup.Value);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public static class NumberExtensions
{
    public static int[] FindAllIndexof<T>(this IEnumerable<T> values, T val)
    {
        return values.Select((b, i) => object.Equals(b, val) ? i : -1).Where(i => i != -1).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Result:

Beta is missing in positions 1

Power is missing in positions 5

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Totally helps the situation.
Just trying to figure out easier options.

Comment: Also need to know which array has the above missing. : Beta is missing from position 1 in test2 array
Power is missing from position 6 in test2 array